# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\ln(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function, digamma-function

Can a step-by-step answer be shown how to prove: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\ln(x)dx = -\frac{{\pi^\frac{1}{2}}}{4}(\gamma+\ln(4))$$

I have a feeling differentiating under the integral sign could be done, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: there is a typo in the title, the integral indicate does not converge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- x^{2}} \, x^{u -1} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \, \Gamma\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)$$
and differentiate with respect to $u$ to obtain
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- x^{2}} \, x^{u -1} \, \ln(x) \,  dx = \frac{1}{4} \, \Gamma\left(\frac{u}{2}\right) \, \psi\left(\frac{u}{2}\right).$$
Set $u =1$ and use the appropriate value of the digamma function to obtain the desired result.